# Big 'O' - time complexity of function

Tags: python, function, time-complexity, big-o

Trying to find the time complexity of a function.

The function is:

```
def test(self, alt):

    same = Sample()
    for i in self.items:
        if alt.func1(i):
            same.func2(i)

    return same
```

`func1` has a complexity of O(s) where s is the size of self.

`func2` has a complexity of O(1).

If `func1` was O(1) then I know it would be

O(1 + n * n) = O(1 + n^2) = O(n^2)

But I need to work it out with `func1` being O(s)

EDIT:

My mistake, I didn't add that:

`Sample()` is O(1)

Comment: "If func1 was O(1) then I know it would be

O(1 + n * n) = O(1 + n^2) = O(n^2)"

And how exactly do you know that?

Comment: What is _n_ in your question ?

Comment: I'm guessing I am wrong with that complexity then, I thought I had the right understanding but clearly not. Sorry. What would that be as well? Not sure where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the `func1` at each iteration within your `for` loop the complexity would depend on the length of `self.items`, `func1` and creating the `same` instance.

So if the length of `self.items` is `n` and the complexity of creating the `same` is `x` the total complexity will be calculated based on following equation:

```
x + ns
```

The complexity of aforementioned equation is depend on X, that said if X is larger than `ns` it would be `O(x)` otherwise it's `O(ns)`. In a general way you can writ it down like follows:

```
O(max{x, ns})
```

Also note that if `func1` was O(1) the complexity wouldn't be like what you claim. It would be `O(max{x, n})`.

Comment: So does that mean the Big O complexity is linear time (O(n)) because n is the significant part that has the most affect? Apologies if I've misinterpreted it.

Comment: You can't say that unless you're aware of the `x`. If `ns` is greater than `x` and `s` is not a factor of `n` then the whole complexity would be `O(n)`.

Comment: Ok I think I've made a mistake. I know that creating `same` as an instance of `Sample()` is constant time (O(1)). So would that make it O(n)?

Comment: @user7262738 No it'd be `O(ns)`. If `s` is not a factor of  `n` then it would be `O(n)`.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand it enough to apply it how I need. Really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, just a quick follow up. Does it mean that if `func1` is O(1) and considering `Sample()` is O(1) too, does that mean the complexity is O(2+n) = O(n)?

Comment: Yes, it would be O(n). @Kasramvd you should remove the 's' in your last line.

Comment: @user7262738 You can tell this to community as well by accepting the answer ;-).